# Conditional contraints in linear programming for non boolean variables

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, constraint-programming, gurobi

Question 1 : x , y are integer non negative variables

i have a condition - if x > 0 then y=0

Question 2 : a , b , c , d , e are integer non negative variables
             if any one of above > 0 then other 4 will be zero.

How to formulate above constraint as linear equations.I know how to handle above for Boolean variables but could not do for integer variable. I tried searching in other forums and WEB but could not get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point try creating some additional boolean variables, one for each of your non boolean variables. Then you can use a typical 'big m' modelling for each. Once you have something that works you can try reworking it to get a better model.

Comment: Thanks for reply , could you please give an example with equations.

Comment: @MohammadShariq Just google indicator-variables in MIP or read [AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~mlh/algkon/ip_tricks.pdf) (e.g. chapter 7.4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical implication in CPLEX (if-then). Please check out the following page: [Logical constraints for CPLEX](http://[http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.2.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/OPL_Studio/_pubskel/globals/eclipse_and_xplatform/ps_opl578.html)